# Decision Tree for MergeSort

Tags: mergesort, decision-tree

If a decision tree for merge-sort has 2^k elements, wouldn't the longest **and** shortest path in that tree be the depth? i.e.:

2^k log 2^k

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To clarify a few things from your question - when you say 2^k elements, do you mean "a decision tree for merge sort when run on 2^k elements," or "there is a decision tree somewhere, it's a decision tree for mergesort, and it has 2^k nodes/leaves?" Also, can you elaborate on what the meaning of the number you've shown above is? What quantity is that number counting?

Comment: Thank you! A decision tree for mergesort when run on 2^k elements. I know that the complexity of merge-sort is n log n, n being the number of elements, so translating that to a decision tree, it is represented as n = 2^k, that is the longest path to a node will be 2^k log 2^k.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at 2^k log 2^k? Also, remember that log 2^k = k.

Comment: I think am misunderstanding how to use complexity to find the path length. I Know that mergesort is linear, so it is T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + O(n), which simplifies to O(n log n). I am treating as a binary tree, so the number of steps to get to any node in a leaf in a binary try is n log n steps. I just substituted the n for 2^k, as I assumed n and 2^k are interchangeable as they represent the number of elements.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the number of steps to get to the leaf of a binary trie with n nodes is n log n? Are you sure you didn't mean a binary trie with n! nodes?

Comment: That is what I understood as what the path length would be looking it up it looks like I am incorrect, trying to work it out. Although If I am dealing with the number of nodes n, I don't understand why I need to represent it as n!. The number of elements is 2^k then the number of leaf nodes is 2^k-1, if the tree is balanced isn't it? So then wouldn't the number of steps just be k-1. If I represent the number of leaf nodes as it as n!, then the longest path would be lg n!. On the right path here? Trying to tie this all together.

Comment: You're on the right track here! If you have a perfectly balanced binary tree with L leaf nodes, then the the path length will be log L. The way you get to a lower bound on the runtime of a sorting algorithm is by using the fact that if you have n total elements, there are n! ways of ordering them, and the algorithm therefore has to have a tree with at least n! leaves (otherwise, it can't tell two different orders apart from one another).

Comment: So given that, using 2^k from my example, 2^k element => n elements. Therefore, the longest path  lg (2^k)! ? The lower bound (shortest path being) lg 2^k, or just k?

Comment: And can't lg n! be rewritten as n lg n??

Comment: If you have 2^k leaves, yes, the longest path has length k. (Well, that, plus or minus one.) And log n! is Theta(n log n) due to Stirling’s approximation.